# What is the process for reverting and cherry picking unwanted pull request from master while deploying it to master

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Deployment Design

[image]

Below are the steps that I was thinking to implement for the DevOps Deployment

1. Create features1 (user1) and feature2 (user2) and then create Pull Request (1583,1584) to merge to Master branch.
2. Move it to Acceptance environment for developer or business user testing, smoking testing etc.
3. Create milestone once a week for production deployment (every Monday)
4. now let's say I just want 1583 feature to land to production environment but 1584 feature is not required so I will revert 1584 PR specifically from master branch and then do my deployment to production
5. after production deployment, I will cherry pick 1584 PR and then merge it to master branch again.

This is the typical design I was thinking to implement, only one burden here that I have to carry by this design is that let's say an old feature PR is there in acceptance and user doesn't want to move since two month to production , so every time we need to revert and cherry pick that item from master branch.

Kindly let me know if you see any future hurdles for this design or any suggestions is most welcome.

As mentioned above, I am going to implement this design but wanted to know if my deployment design is correct or can be improvise further, any other challenges that I might face ?

Comment: Implement feature toggling practices in your application so you can disable features that aren't ready to be shipped *without* having to deal with messy un-merges.

Comment: @DanielMann - kindly send me some reference or link of any document or any video for feature toggling method used in Azure Devops with Azure repos git ... Also let's suppose one feature (invoke a child pipeline) is hidden for a parent pipeline with the help of feature flag .. but when we run the pipeline ... will children pipeline will run or not run ?

Comment: I am recommending an approach to **application development**, not to version control. There are plenty of resources available on the concept of feature toggling and how to go about implementing it in your application.